# Unable to solve sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'IFDRational'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have looked online but have not been able to find out what the following error means?
I am trying add the gps data from the images into the database. The data has been stored in a dictionary.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'IFDRational'
```

The data that gets fed into the function is the following dictionary

```
{'image_name': 'test4.JPG', 'date_time': '2022:09:13 10:22:01', 'latitude': 37.94335555555555, 'longitude': 23.84112222222222, 'altitude': 251.91022778025905}
```

```
import psycopg2

from meta_data import get_meta_data

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# connection
db_string = "postgresql://xxxxx:xxxxxxx@xxxxx:5432/xxxxx"

db = create_engine(db_string)
conn = db.connect()
print("Connected successfully........")



data = get_meta_data('test4.JPG')
# print(data)

def insert_data(data):
    db.execute(
        "INSERT INTO images (image_name, date_time, latitude, longitude, altitude) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
        (data['image_name'], data['date_time'], data['latitude'], data['longitude'], data['altitude']))    
    print("Data inserted successfully........")

insert_data(data)
```

Thanks to the tip of @snakecharmerb I was able to solve it.

I forgot to type cast my altitude to a float. This is how i did it.

```
alt = float(exif_data['GPSInfo'][6])
```

Comment: I means that t least one of the values you are trying to insert is of a type `IFDRational`, and psycopg2 doesn't know what to do with such a type.  It's probably one of lat/lang/altitude - do these values come from a specialist package?  You need to convert it to a type that psycopg2 can handle, and that matches the data type of the column(s) in the target table.  [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types).

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks for the tip! It was indeed a value that i hadn't type casted to a float! This is how i solved it!